# Firebase v9 ,Cannot get document from a nested collection

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I feel like it was easier to get subcollection in v8 ,It's been like 2 days trying to do it the new way but I gave up.

Im building a simple react social media app for learning purposes. where each user logs in and be able to post some text (and images but not atm),
I have a main collection for Users and it has the users ID .each of these users have a collection called Posts and it contains all the user posts.

[image: here i want to access the Post collection for each user and then access the posts]

I can do so by entering the UID of each user like so

[image: but I can only access the current user id]

so what can i do to access the Users collection then get ALL the users and be able to access the Posts subcollection?

ps : sorry if any part of this question is unclear ,english isn't my first language and it's my first time posting here. appreciate any help!.

Comment: hi Vito and welcome on StackOverflow. Could you post your code with a minimal reproductible user case ?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to fetch posts from all the users, you are looking for `collectionGroup` queries using which you can fetch documents in all the sub-collections named as 'posts'. You can run a `collectionGroup` query using Modular SDK (V9) as shown below:

```js
import { getFirestore, getDocs, collectionGroup } from "firebase/firestore"
const db = getFirestore()

const allPosts = await getDocs(collectionGroup(db, "posts"))
```

Comment: thank you!!! ,dont know how i did not see it

Comment: What if you want to fetch all posts from a specific user by its ID?

Comment: @MartinNordström you can use `getDocs(collectionGroup(db, "posts"), where("id", "==", "userId"))`

Comment: Sorry for creating this thread. This is my first time using firebase. This is my V8 code that I'm trying to migrate,`firestore.collection("users").doc(auth.currentUser.uid)..collection("coworkingSessions").doc(slug);`. I am thankful for the help I can get

Comment: @MartinNordström simply `getDoc(doc(db, 'users', auth.currentUser.uid, 'coworkingSessions', slug))`

Answer (score 0):

I have a structure like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vciQu.png)

"posts" is a collection and it contains different "user IDs" documents and the "user IDs" contain a collection called "photos" which contain different documents which contain information about a post a user has created

To access all the posts of a user, I made use of

```
 const docRef = doc(db, 'posts', auth.currentUser.uid)
 const docSnap = await getDocs(collection(docRef, "photos"))
 docSnap.forEach((doc) => {
    // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
    console.log(doc.id, ' => ', doc.data())
 })
```

Answer (score -1):

```
const docRef = doc(db, "Users", currentUser.uid);
const docSnap = await getDocs(collection(docRef, "Posts");)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.